# How to avoid starvation in multi producer and consumer?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

1. Consider here 2 producer threads and one consumer thread.
2. Suppose queue is full.
3. Two producer thread goes to wait state because queue is full.
4. Consumer thread takes element from queue and notifyAll so one of the producer thread adds element and comes out and another producer thread remains in wait state and again another producer threads add elements and coming out.
5. So if you observe there are chances that one thread can be in wait state always.

How to avoid this ?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

interface BlockingQueueCustom<E> {

      void put(E item)  throws InterruptedException ;

      E take()  throws InterruptedException;
}

class LinkedBlockingQueueCustom<E> implements BlockingQueueCustom<E> {

    private List<E> queue;
    private int maxSize; // maximum number of elements queue can hold at a time.

    public LinkedBlockingQueueCustom(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        queue = new LinkedList<E>();
    }

    public synchronized void put(E item) throws InterruptedException {

         while(queue.size() == maxSize) {
            this.wait();
        }

        queue.add(item);
        this.notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized E take() throws InterruptedException {

        while(queue.size() == 0) {
            this.wait();
        }

        this.notifyAll();
        return queue.remove(0);

    }

}

public class BlockingQueueCustomTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingQueueCustom<Integer> b = new LinkedBlockingQueueCustom<Integer>(10);
        System.out.println("put(11)");
        b.put(11);
        System.out.println("put(12)");
        b.put(12);
        System.out.println("take() > " + b.take());
        System.out.println("take() > " + b.take());

    }
}
```

Comment: add some small random number to the wait time, there will then be a 50% chance that the other producer wakes up first. or have the buffer not notify producers until there is room for each to add content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. One is to use standard `ArrayBlockingQueue` calling two arguments constructor. In this case queue will process threads in FIFO order and producers will add elements in the queue in the same order they've tried to put elements into the queue.

```
/**
 * Creates an {@code ArrayBlockingQueue} with the given (fixed)
 * capacity and the specified access policy.
 *
 * @param capacity the capacity of this queue
 * @param fair if {@code true} then queue accesses for threads blocked
 *        on insertion or removal, are processed in FIFO order;
 *        if {@code false} the access order is unspecified.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code capacity < 1}
 */
public ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity, boolean fair) {...}
```

Another option is to use `ReentrantReadWriteLock` with fairness parameter turned on instead of `synchronized` block.

```
/**
 * Creates a new {@code ReentrantReadWriteLock} with
 * the given fairness policy.
 *
 * @param fair {@code true} if this lock should use a fair ordering policy
 */
public ReentrantReadWriteLock(boolean fair) {...}
```

This is an example of how to convert `synchronized` block into code with `ReentrantReadWriteLock`: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/06/java-lock-and-condition-example-producer-consumer.html

Comment: can we simply keep private final Lock aLock = new ReentrantLock(true);  and it would solve starvation problem ?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to call `unlock()` in `finally` block. Unlike `synchronized` block for lock objects lock is not released by default when you exit the code block guarded by lock object.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `wait` and `notify` has been outdated [since 2005](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140767.html) as it was limited in what it could do.

For your specific problem, I really suggest refactoring your solution to use the [Java Semaphore class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). You will see that you can set a fairness parameter. This parameter will ensure that allocation is done in a FIFO manner so that once one of your threads acquires a permit and puts the data into your queue, it is brought to the end of the line when blocking again (and as such, the second thread will gain priority).

Hope this helps.